# How to identify column types during sql injection?

Tags: oracle, security, sql-injection

Situation is following:

I have identified sql injection attack vector, and have following information about target table:

- It has six columns. (Identified using "order by").
- I can see output of 3 of them (table is displayed). two seems kind of enum value (integer in database?), and one is a date. I have very strong suspicion that col #6 is date column.
- I'm almost sure the database is oracle. (ROWNUM works and LIMIT gives error).
- I don't have error messages (always generic text is returned - "something went wrong").
- Frontend is PHP if that matters. But there might be middle layer between it and database (e.g. java service), so I'm not sure where the query is being constructed.

E.g. following search query works as expected:

`test' AND ROWNUM <= 5 ORDER BY 6--`

EDIT-FROM-HERE:

Ok after help from comments, following query works:

`test' UNION ALL SELECT null,null,null,null,null,null FROM dual--`

(I was missing `FROM dual` part. Thank you @kordirko very much!)

This query adds one empty record in the output table (it is visually visible), so I'm definitely on the right track!

Now following line also works:

`test' UNION ALL SELECT null,null,null,n't',null,null FROM dual--`

I correctly identified 4th column and now it displays uppercase(?) letter `T` where I expected it to appear. So far so good. But it gives error when I input any string longer than 1 char! So following gives an error:

`test' UNION ALL SELECT null,null,null,n'test',null,null FROM dual--`

I'm no expert in SQL injection, and especially ORACLE (though have experience with MsSql).

I think the problem is something unicode-ansi-whateverencoding-related. For other rows (selected by original query before my `UNION ALL SELECT` addition) the 4th column gives multi-character normal strings. But when I try to inject desired string, it only works if it's one character, and also misteriously displays it in uppercase. I think this must be some encoding problem. I just discovered I needed `n` prefix for unicode string after 1 hour of searching and struggling. Maybe some Oracle gurus can quickly spot what mistake do I have in my query?

Comment: which db is it? mysql? oracle? getting metadata about a query is highly db specific and something that works in mysql will be useless in oracle.

Comment: @MarcB, The database is Oracle, as I have written in the question :)

Comment: simply use your query with literals and try to replace one by one with function calls to_number (which returns NUMBER) and to_date (which returns date) and you will see. Most probably you will not find any other datatypes then VARCHAR2, NUMBER and DATE. So you have 3^6 tries.

Comment: On Oracle you have to append `FROM dual` if you want to make union all: `test' UNION ALL SELECT null,null,null,null,null,null FROM dual`, see this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d6774/3 The first query in this example has `FROM dual` clause and works fine, while the second without `FROM dual` gives the syntax error.

Comment: @kordirko thank you very much, your correction helped - I was missing `from dual` thing. But now I'm unable to replace `null` values with any string. I updated the question accordingly. Please help if you can, thanks!

Comment: Um.... is this *your* database you're breaking into?  The fact that you're not sure what the database is implies you are not authorized to "test" the security of this website.

Comment: @JonHeller It is called pen. testing, google it ;)

Comment: You should make sure it’s actually an Oracle database with an additional literal like `EXISTS (SELECT banner FROM v$version WHERE banner LIKE 'Oracle%')`.

Comment: [Same question on Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/87553/539)